# Trying and failing to simulate a ST2110 Stream with gStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Im trying to simulate a ST2110 stream with gStreamer to send it from Host A to Host B like this. The problem is, I have no clue how gstreamer works.

|Sender|------>Switch----->|Receiver|

Good to know:
OS: Ubuntu

LinuxPTP: To sync servers

gStreamer* & Telestream PRISM*: To create St2110 signal

Tcpdump: To capture the traffic on Host B

Wireshark ST2110 dissector: Filter the pcaps

EBU-LIST: To upload the capture files and check if the stream is/was St2110 compliant.

Bandwidth: up to 10gb/s

gStreamer Sender:
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin 
videotestsrc horizontal-speed=2 !  
video/x-raw,width=1280,height=720,framerate=30/1,format=UYVP ! rtpvrawpay pt=102 ! queue ! 
rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! queue ! 
udpsink host=233.0.1.2 port=5005 render-delay=0 rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! 
udpsink host=233.0.1.2 port=5005 sync=false async=false 
audiotestsrc ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! 
rtpL24pay ! application/x-rtp, pt=103, payload=103, clock-rate=48000, channels=2 ! 
rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_1 rtpbin.send_rtp_src_1 ! 
udpsink host=233.0.1.2 port=5007 render-delay=0 rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_1 ! 
udpsink host=233.0.1.2 port=5007 sync=false async=false

gStreamer Receiver:
gst-launch-1.0 rtpbin name=rtpbin udpsrc multicast-group=233.0.1.2 ! autovideosink sync=true

result:
[EBU-LIST result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41ts4.png)

As you can see, the problem is Audio, Cinst, VRX and Video Latency.

C: Network compatibility model. Measueres the packet delay variation by the sender.
If the packetnumber exceeds CMAX, the bucket overflows and we lose packets.
[Network Compatibility Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oewv.png)

VRX: Virtual receive buffer model: Second "bucket". Its drainrate is based on the read schedule of the receiver.
[VRX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTLoz.png)

Audio: [Audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp2Mq.png)

source:
https://tech.ebu.ch/docs/groups/list/Live_IP_Software_Toolkit-paper.pdf

My question is, what gStreamer settings do I change or add to fix those 4 problems (Cinst, VRX, Latency)?
How can I simulate those "leaky buckets" C and VRX.
On a sidenote: I tested the setup with a hardware st2110 signal generator and the EBU-List result was 100% ST2110 compliant. So the problem must or should be the sender/gStreamer.

I would appreciate any help.

I tested different gStreamer settings but its not very effective if you dont know how gStreamer works.

edit1: limiting the bandwidth with tc qdisc fixed Cinst!